# How large will the stack frame of this function be in bytes?

Tags: c, stack

```
static void g(int v, int w) {
  int x, y, z;

  x= n * v;

}
```

How many bytes would the stack frame of function g() be?

Comment: It's up to the compiler. It can be [as low as zero](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9jzjfo).

Comment: It could be zero, it could be megabytes. The function may have been optimised out of existence due to the "as if" rule, which allows implementations to do whatever they like, provided the observable behaviour, as per the standard, is identical. In fact, the ISO C standard mentions the word 'stack' exactly *zero* times, so a stack may not even exist.

Comment: could it be 28, assuming everything is used?

Comment: @RaymondChen: Hmmm. Is the return address considered part of the frame? :-)

Comment: Asznee, yes, it *could* be 28. It could also be any other non-negative integer :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Who said the return address is on the stack? :-) https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/orobW3

Answer (score 0):

Because it's `static` and small, the function will probably be inlined into some other function and the parameters will probably be in registers.

However, because it does nothing (the calculated value in `x` isn't returned and isn't used, and there's no side-effects) it's more likely that the entire function will be deleted.

In either case, for all sane compilers (with optimizations enabled), it won't use any stack.

Comment: could it be 28, assuming everything is used?

Comment: @AszneeJoneson You haven't specified the size of an `int`.  Heck, you haven't even specified how many bits there are in a byte.  Those are ***not*** fixed values.

Comment: @AszneeJoneson: Assuming everything is used; then it depends on calling conventions the compiler felt like using (which may not be a standard ABI because it's `static`). If a standard ABI is used; then it depends on which one. For an example, for both common 64-bit 80x86 ABIs; parameters will be passed in registers, the "return address" will consume 8 bytes of stack, but the stack will be aligned to a 16 byte boundary; so you'd probably expect it to use 16 bytes of stack space (ignoring the funky stuff - "shadow space" or "red zone").

Comment: @Brendan On the other hand, on a register-rich RISC architecture, everything is probably in registers, even the return address. A lightweight leaf function consumes no stack. On the third hand, security or debugger options may introduce canaries, frame pointers, profiling checkpoints, and who-knows-what-else. So yeah, could be anything.